# JSP Expression Language Error Behavior?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, el

I'm running Tomcat 6.0.18 on Linux.

I have a JSP that uses a bean like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="helper"
             type="com.example.SomeType"
             scope="request"/>
```

The page references an attribute of `helper` with the expression language like this:

```
<!-- This works properly, but could fail silently if the bean name is incorrect. -->
<div><p>Here's some stuff: ${helper.stuff}</div>
```

During some refactoring in which I missed an occurrence of the name `helper`, I noticed that **no error is raised** if the name `helper` is written incorrectly. Not on the screen, and not in my log files. Nothing is produced for the expression language snippet in the output:

```
<!-- Wrong name! "foo" should be "helper" but no error is observed (other than missing ouput)! -->
<div><p>Here's some stuff: ${foo.stuff}</div>
```

Now, an error *is* raised (my custom error page displays and I see an exception in my log file) if I use the following JSP syntax with an incorrect name for `helper`:

```
<!-- Wrong name, but an error is raised. -->
<div><p>Here's some stuff: <jsp:getProperty name="foo" property="stuff"/></div>
```

In this case, the log records this entry:

```
SEVERE: requestURI: /some.jsp servletName: jsp statusCode: 500
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Attempted a bean operation on a null object.
```

For completeness, the `jsp:getProperty` syntax works properly when the bean name is correct:

```
<!-- Works properly, protects me from an incorrect name, but is more verbose than EL. -->
<div><p>Here's some stuff: <jsp:getProperty name="helper" property="stuff"/></div>
```

**Why don't I see an error when I write ${foo.stuff}? Is there some configuration option that controls error reporting in such cases?**

Comment: Just to affirm what others said, this is a purposeful feature of EL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is covered in section 1.6 of the [Expression Language Specification Version 2.1](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html).

> To evaluate expr-a[expr-b]:
>
> If value-a is null:
>
> - If expr-a[expr-b] is the last property being resolved:
>
>   - If the expression is a value expression and
>       ValueExpression.getValue(context) was
>       called to initiate this expression
>       evaluation, return null.
>   - Otherwise, throw PropertyNotFoundException. *trying to
>       de-reference null for an lvalue*
> - Otherwise, return null.

(EL unifies the . and [] operators)

Comment: Thanks for this answer @McDowell. To clarify: "ValueExpression.getValue(context)" == using the EL to read a value (which is what I'm doing in this question), and "trying to de-reference null for an lvalue" == using the EL to write a value. Section 1.4 of the spec discusses the rationale for the observed behavior. Oh, and "return null" means "produce the empty string" in this context - Spec section 1.18.2

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way that EL works.

${helper} evaluates to null so EL just returns "" and doesn't attempt to evalulate the rest of the expression.

It's kinda handy feature in some cases:

```
${myBean.property1.name}
```

will work if even if property1 is null, thus I don't have to write just to prevent an NPE:

```
<c:if test="${not empty myBean.property1}">${myBean.property1.name}</c:if>
```